# Minecraft Bedrock Scripting API Error world.beforeEvents.chatSend.subscribe

Tags: javascript, minecraft

When I load my world or `/reload` I've got this error

```
[Scripting][error]-Plugin [MinolyaReborn - 1.0.0] - [main.js] ran with error: [TypeError: cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined    at <anonymous> (events/sendMessageWithTag.js:2)]
```

This my `main.js` :

```js
import "./Sticks/healthStick.js";
import "./events/sendMessageWithTag.js";

console.warn("§6[Addon]§r all files loaded");
```

and this is my `sendMessageWithTag.js`:

```js
import { world } from '@minecraft/server';
world.beforeEvents.chatSend.subscribe((eventData) => {
    const player = eventData.sender;
    switch (eventData.message) {
        case '!creative':
            eventData.cancel = true;
            player.runCommandAsync('gamemode c');
            break;
        case '!survival':
            eventData.cancel = true;
            player.runCommandAsync('gamemode s');
            break;
        default: break;
    }
});
```

my manifest use this dependencies:

```json
{
    "module_name": "@minecraft/server",
    "version": "1.9.0"
},
{
    "module_name": "@minecraft/server-gametest",
    "version": "1.0.0-beta"
},
{
    "module_name": "@minecraft/server-ui",
    "version": "1.2.0-beta"
},
{
    "module_name": "@minecraft/server-admin",
    "version": "1.0.0-beta"
}
```

I would add chat event so I went in [his web page](https://wiki.bedrock.dev/scripting/custom-command.html)
the only (except Microsoft page) who use:

`world.beforeEvents.chatSend.subscribe`

How can I fix it?

Comment: world.beforeEvents.chatSend` is `undefined` so either that's the wrong property, or it's not fully loaded. Check with some debugging herre to see what properties `beforeEvents` has.